# Bootstrap- Align two <select> horizontally

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

These two select from the same control-group are getting displayed vertically. I want to display them horizontally. I tried doing inline-block on CSS, but there are some other `<div>` with the same control-group class, with different width and margin settings. Changing the class name doesn't help either.

```
<div class="control-group">
     <label for="week">Dispatch schedule:</label>

    <select class="form-control" name="week" id="week" title="Delivery" style="width:110px;">


      <option data-val='OPEN' value="READY">Ready</option>


      <option data-val='CLOSE' value="1st WEEK">1st Week</option>

      <option data-val='CLOSE' value="2nd WEEK">2nd Week</option>

       <option data-val='CLOSE' value="3rd WEEK">3rd Week</option>


    </select>


        <select name="Delivery" id="Delivery" disabled="">

        <option value="OPEN">Open</option>
      <option value="CLOSE">Close</option>
    </select>

        <script>
                                var category = document.getElementById('Delivery');
    document.getElementById('week').onchange = function() {
      var optionSelected = this.options[this.selectedIndex];
      if (optionSelected.textContent != '-') {
        if (optionSelected.dataset.val === 'OPEN') {
          category.value = 'OPEN';
        } else {
          category.value = 'CLOSE';
        }
      } else {
        category.value = '';
      }
    }

                                </script>

                                </div>
```

Comment: This code is showing them horizontally grouped. If you have some other `div` which are causing the problem, try `col` bootstrap classes

Answer (score 0):

you could use multi column grid
and set no of columns or width accordingly.

fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/nLddvkw6/1

**

```
<div class="control-group">



<div class="row">
  <div class="border col-xs-4"><label for="week">Dispatch schedule:</label></div>
  <div class="border col-xs-4"><select class="form-control" name="week" id="week" title="Delivery" style="width:110px;">


      <option data-val='OPEN' value="READY">Ready</option>


      <option data-val='CLOSE' value="1st WEEK">1st Week</option>

      <option data-val='CLOSE' value="2nd WEEK">2nd Week</option>

       <option data-val='CLOSE' value="3rd WEEK">3rd Week</option>


    </select>
</div>
  <div class="border col-xs-4">  <select class="form-control" name="Delivery" id="Delivery" disabled="" style="width:110px;">

        <option value="OPEN">Open</option>
      <option value="CLOSE">Close</option>
    </select></div>
</div>

</div>
```

Comment: You should please remove the link on top because otherwise this answer will be flagged.

Answer (score 0):

Flexbox version:

```
<div class="control-group">
     <label for="week">Dispatch schedule:</label>
      <div style="display: flex; flex-direction: row;">
         <select></select>
         <select></select>
      </div>
</div>
```

Bootstrap version:

```
<div class="control-group">
     <label for="week">Dispatch schedule:</label>
      <div class="row>
         <div class="col-md-6>
             <select></select>
         </div>
         <div class="col-md-6>
              <select></select>
         </div>
      </div>
</div>
```

CSS version:

```
<div class="control-group">
     <label for="week" style="display: block; width: 100%;">Dispatch schedule:</label>
     <select style="display: float: width: 49%;></select>
     <select style="display: float: width: 49%;></select> 
</div>
```